# why Package tesseract is not available?

Tags: python, android, package, tesseract, termux

Everytime that I try to install Tesseract with pkg install tesseract, always says:

````
Checking availability of current mirror: ok
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package tesseract is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'tesseract' has no installation candidate```
````

Comment: what system do you use? Maybe there is no `tesseract` for your system. Maybe nobody have time to create it or nobody need it. So you will have to compile it from source code - and it can be big challange.

Comment: i used termux sir

Comment: `termux` is not as system but some program on some system. Do you mean `android`? As I said it looks like nobody created `tesseract` for `android` - so you can't install it. It may need to get source code and compile it. But this is big challenge. OR you have find someone who already compiled it and put it somewhere on internet.

Comment: yes sir i mean android

Comment: found with Google: [Tesseract4Android](https://github.com/adaptech-cz/Tesseract4Android)